# Why does one \tableofcontents give two tables of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I just want a table of contents with two columns by the `etoc` package. But the following code typesets two TOCs (please see the attached figure). Why? What's wrong with my code?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\etocmulticol{}%
\tableofcontents
\section{first}
\subsection{subfirst}
\section{second}
\subsection{subsecond}
\section{third}
\subsection{subthird}
\section{fourth}
\subsection{subfourth}
\section{fifth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\etocmulticol{}` gives you the two-column ToC and `\tableofcontents` gives you the single-column ToC. You call both macros and therefore you get two ToCs. If you only want the two-column ToC, you need to delete `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I had alway thought that `\etocmulticol` is only for set not for typeset!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mixed up the macro `\etocmulticolstyle` with the other macro `\etocmulticol`. While the first macro is used to set the style for all ToCs that you can then call using `tableofcontents`, the second macro just directly typesets one ToC styled in the given way without changing the overall style of other ToCs.

So, you should either delete `\tableofcontents` from your code, or you change `\etocmulticol{}` to `\etocmulticolstyle{}`, for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\etocmulticolstyle{\textbf{\large Table of Contents}}

\tableofcontents

\section{first}
\subsection{subfirst}
\section{second}
\subsection{subsecond}
\section{third}
\subsection{subthird}
\section{fourth}
\subsection{subfourth}
\section{fifth}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You create two table of contents. One is `\etocmulticol`, the other one is `\tableofcontent`. If you comment out one of them, you will get only one.